Zoom (transform:scale) picture outside of the parent div box
I'm trying to make a simple "when hovering mouse over picture, enlarge picture" logic work. The problem: it's on a google-site website.


.zoom {
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
  transition: transform .2s; /* Animation */
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
}

.zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(2); /* (150% zoom - Note: if the zoom is too large, it will go outside of the viewport) */
}
<div class="zoom">
  <img
    src="https://picsum.photos/106/79"
    width="106px"
    height="79px"
  /> 
</div>

<span class="summary">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</span>



This is  what I have been doing so far -- a span, with a "zoom" div next to it. Unfortunately, these elements are packed in a sequence of iframe-html-body-iframe-html-body-iframe-html-body (I can paste the code here if helpful, but it would be a bit difficult to find all the declarations).
I suppose it is because of these parent elements than when I hover over my image, it does indeed enlarge. However, it cuts off at the upper right corner (where it extends outside of the box assigned to this span-div combination.
Is there a way to tell the zoom to "overlap over any other element that is at a higher level of hierarchy?

Any content inside iframe can not overcome its parent iframe height and width, you can try controlling iframe height and width according to content via JS if you access.

@vaku to be clear, think of the website as a table with two elements per row - left element is a text field, the right element is the image field (each is an iframe). You're saying the only way to have one iframe's content be bigger  is by making the iframe itself bigger, thus "pushing out" the neighboring iframes? In other words, the picture wouldn't be lieing over the text?

Can you only style elements inside the iframes - or do you have styling "access" to the parent document as well? If the latter - just scale the whole iframe then? Then it would automatically overlap the text content next to it.
